# first function must complete before calling second function

Tags: javascript

For my example I have three functions that must execute completely before going to the next function. I know I can place the second function in the first function, etc, but I need the flexibility to execute functions in various orders.

Upon doing research it appears I need to do a "Callback" but don't understand how to apply it to my situation. Here is what I have so far. Of course the way it is it goes through all three functions without stopping other than for the alerts. Can someone help me here or at least point me in the direction I should consider?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h3>Validates Input Values</h3>
    <form name='checkout_form'>
        <table id="table_form">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <INPUT type="text" id="xFirstName" STYLE="color: #3366CC; text-align: left; font-family: Times; font-size: 12px; background-color: transparent; border:dotted; border-color:#7b0000; border-width:1px; width:180px" name="first_name" value="" size="14" onKeyup="autotab(this,document.donate_form.last_name)"
                    maxlength=14 onkeypress="return inputLimiter(event,'NameCharacters')">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <INPUT type="text" id="xLastName" STYLE="color: #3366CC; text-align: left; font-family: Times; font-size: 12px; background-color: transparent; border:dotted; border-color:#7b0000; border-width:1px; width:180px" name="last_name" value="" size="14" onKeyup="autotab(this,document.donate_form.amount)"
                        maxlength=14 onkeypress="return inputLimiter(event,'NameCharacters')">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zip Code:</td>
                <td>
                    <INPUT type="text" id="xZipCode" STYLE="color: #3366CC; text-align: left;  
font-family: Times; font-size: 12px; background-color: transparent; border:dotted; border-color:#7b0000; border-width:1px; width:180px" name="zip" value="" size="14" onKeyup="autotab(this,document.donate_form.amount)" maxlength=14 onkeypress="return inputLimiter(event,'Numbers')">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <button onclick="myFunction_Varify()">VALIDATE</button>
    <script>
    function myFunction_Varify() {
      myFunction_firstName();
      myFunction_lastName();
      myFunction_zipCode();
    }

    function myFunction_firstName() {
      vFirstName = document.getElementById("xFirstName").value;
      if (vFirstName == "") {
        document.forms['checkout_form'].elements['first_name'].focus();
        alert("No FIRST NAME entered");
      }
    }

    function myFunction_lastName() {
      vLastName = document.getElementById("xLastName").value;
      if (vLastName == "") {
        document.forms['checkout_form'].elements['last_name'].focus();
        alert("No LAST NAME entered");
        return false;
      }
    }

    function myFunction_zipCode() {
      vZipCode = document.getElementById("xZipCode").value;
      if (vZipCode == "") {
        document.forms['checkout_form'].elements['zip'].focus();
        alert("No ZIP CODE entered");
        return false;
      }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should strongly consider using indentation while writing code. It'll make reading and debugging much easier.

Comment: I did copy and paste with indentation but apparently it does not format correctly on this site as I tried to manually reset with indentation. Will try and reformat if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you are && them

```
    function myFunction_Varify() {
      myFunction_firstName() && myFunction_lastName() && myFunction_zipCode();
    }

    function myFunction_firstName() {
      vFirstName = document.getElementById("xFirstName").value;
      if (vFirstName == "") {
        document.forms['checkout_form'].elements['first_name'].focus();
        alert("No FIRST NAME entered");
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    function myFunction_lastName() {
      vLastName = document.getElementById("xLastName").value;
      if (vLastName == "") {
        document.forms['checkout_form'].elements['last_name'].focus();
        alert("No LAST NAME entered");
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    function myFunction_zipCode() {
      vZipCode = document.getElementById("xZipCode").value;
      if (vZipCode == "") {
        document.forms['checkout_form'].elements['zip'].focus();
        alert("No ZIP CODE entered");
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: That did the job. I thought I may need to put in a return true statement somewhere, but would you please be so kind as to explain the why and how of using the &&? You made it so easy. Thanks

Comment: with myFunction_firstName() && myFunction_lastName() && myFunction_zipCode(); the second function will only be called if the first one return true and the third function will only be called if the second one return true. hence this fits nicely with what you need.